# Is there a case where playstore serves both armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a if the device supports both or will i get only one architecture apk out of both

Tags: android, abi, android-app-bundle

> my app uses native ndk so i am using app bundle. When i unzip bundle & check size of each apk it is looking good. But want to know how Play store serves the apk & what apks will be served?

Answer (score 0):

in the documentation you can see that :

> If your app uses only code written in the Java programming language or
>   Kotlin, including all libraries or SDKs, your app is already ready for
>   64-bit devices. If your app uses any native code, or you are unsure if
>   it does, you will need to assess your app and take action

and also you can check  [multiple-APK support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks)

> The concept for using multiple APKs on Google Play is that you have
>   just one entry in Google Play for your application, but different
>   devices might download a different APK. This means that:
>
> You maintain only one set of product details (app description, icons,
>   screenshots, etc.). This also means you cannot charge a different
>   price for different APKs. All users see only one version of your
>   application on Google Play, so they are not confused by different
>   versions you may have published that are "for tablets" or "for
>   phones." All user reviews are applied to the same application listing,
>   even though users on different devices may have different APKs. If you
>   publish different APKs for different versions of Android (for
>   different API levels), then when a user's device receives a system
>   update that qualifies them for a different APK you've published,
>   Google Play updates the user's application to the APK designed for the
>   higher version of Android. Any system data associated with the
>   application is retained (the same as with normal application updates
>   when using a single APK).

Answer (score 0):

As PlayStore strict to upload new apk (which are using native lib) without 64 bit device support, It mean you have to put support for both 32 and 62 bit devices hence you put two lib in your android project and apk size is grow more (like 25-35mb or more than that) and if you want to engage use and increase download so its not a ideal size in that case google introduce new app bundle concept witch minimize the app size according to device.

example : if device is 64 bit support  and xhdpi so its only load 64 bit lib and xhdi folder in that case apk size is down by 30-50%, so its good to upload app bundle on play store if your apk size is more thant 20 mb and you are using native library.

Answer (score 0):

If a device supports both arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a, Play will serve only the 64-bit libraries (i.e. arm64-v8a).
Unless you change the defaults in the bundle configuration, Play always serves the libraries for a single ABI.

You can test that locally using `bundletool extract-apks` command. See the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool